# Selecting max value between values PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I want to select max attribute between two columns on a query. it isn't the whole table max.

Something like that:

```
SELECT MAX(t1.c1, t2.c2)
FROM Table1 as t1, Table2 as t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.t1_id
AND ...... here goes more conditions.
```

I want to each row has mapped value representing the max between `t1.c1` and `t2.c2`

Is that possible ?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful here... Also look at using a `join` instead.

Comment: I think you just want `SELECT GREATEST(t1.c1, t2.c2) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select max(c1)
from (select c1 from t1 union all select c2 from t2) t;
```

Or -- probably more efficient -- use `greatest()`:

```
select greatest(c1, c2)
from (select max(c1) as c1 from t1) t1 cross join
     (select max(c2) as c2 from t2) t2;
```

Comment: where should I add more conditions ? like my answer. I  updated it.

Comment: You would add them in the subqueries.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`greatest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST):

```
SELECT greatest(t1.c1, t2.c2)
FROM Table1 as t1
JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
-- WHERE ...... here goes more conditions
```

Note, I have changed your notation of join to more convenient.